# Missing PNotify closer

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, pnotify

Im using [Pnotify](https://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) plugin, but the closer button is not showing.

```
new PNotify({
                title: 'Sucesso',
                text: response.message,
                type: 'success',
                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                closer: true,
                labels: {close: "Fechar", stick: "Manter"}
            });
```

Any ideas about this behavior?

[image: generated pnotify example]

Included files are:
pnotify.css
pnotify.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After read the [documentation of Pnotify](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify#user-content-buttons-module) you have to wrap `closer` inside the `buttons {}` options and `labels` too.

```
new PNotify({
    title: 'Sucesso',
    text: response.message,
    type: 'success',
    styling: 'bootstrap3',
    buttons: { closer: true, 
        labels: {close: "Fechar", stick: "Manter"}
    },
});
```

Comment: I realized the plugin that came with my bootstrap theme wasn't working correcly. I downloaded it againg from the site. Is working now!  I dont know what to do with this question now